# CMake error that i do not understand

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw

I'm using CMake to compile a project. This is the path to my sources: https://github.com/Ro6afF/Snake . When I type this

```
cd build && cmake ..
```

it prints this:

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineSnakeCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Snake_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Snake_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /home/asd/snake/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.0/CMakeSnakeCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (Project):
  No CMAKE_Snake_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the CMake cache entry
  CMAKE_Snake_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler
  name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeSnakeInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_Snake_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/asd/snake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Can you explain me how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a space in project name: `PROJECT(OpenGL Snake)`. Look at [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) -- that makes `Snake` the language parameter.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you! When I remove the space it wotks.

Comment: It would be good for future readers if the original `CMakeLists.txt` was put in the question. The external link now contains the corrected version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) command incorrectly:

```
PROJECT(OpenGL Snake)
```

The space acts as a separator. That means project name is `OpenGL` and language is `Snake`. CMake knows no such language.

Change the code to something like

```
PROJECT(OpenGL_Snake)
```